# What is the diffrence between List[Double] required: Main.List[Double] in Scala

Tags: scala, types, mismatch

I am new in Scala . Doing some tutorials, I have got  erors:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hello Scala!")       

  sealed trait List[+A]
  case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
  case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match { 
    case Nil => 1.0  
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0  
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
  }

  // this call is incorrect
  product(List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0))
}
```

What is the reason of this error?

```
mismatch; found : List[Double] required: Main.List[Double] product(List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0))
```

Comment: the error  as follows :

Comment: mismatch;
    found   : List[Double]
    required: Main.List[Double]
    product(List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post additional info as comments - [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 3):

`List[Double]` refers to the `List` type defined in Scala's standard library. `Main.List[Double]` refers to the `List` type that you defined yourself.

`List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0)` calls the `apply` method of the standard library's `List` object (because you didn't define a `List` object of your own), which returns an instance of the standard library `List` type, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

is defining a standard Scala `List` of doubles (via the companion `apply()` method), whereas your product method requires an instance of *your* `List` object (defined above). So you should provide an instance of your own (e.g. via your `Cons` case class?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some details

```
 def product(ds: sealed trait List[A+] extends Object ): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(A, _) => A
    case Cons(head: A, tail: List[A]) => head * product(tail)
 }

product(List(3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0))
```

this call is incorrect because method `product` require for input your implementation 
   of `List` not `scala.collection.immutable.List`